# Combinatorics vs probability with replcements

Tags: probability, combinations

I always tried to solve probability problems with permutation/combination style. However, I could not reconcile following probability problems -

**Question 1**. If there are 3 blueberries, 2 chokeberries and 5 strawberries in a bag and if 2 berries are drawn without replacement, what is the probability of drawing out 1 blueberry and 1 chokeberry?

**Probable ans:**

- General probability counting: (3/10)*(2/9) = 1/15
- Cobinatorics[no-repeat]: ($_3C_1$ . $_2C_1$) /$_{10}C_2$ = 2/15 **(!!)**

---

**Question 2**. A jar contains 2 red and 5 green marbles.  A marble is drawn, it's color noted, and put back in the jar.  This process is repeated a total of 4 times. What is the probability that you selected 4 green marbles?

**Probable ans:**

- General probability counting: $(5/7)^4$ = 625/2401
- Cobinatorics[repeat]: *How to solve it with combination? Is it a combination with repetition problem (ie. ball and urns)?*

So my question is what is the issue with 1st question's ans and how to approach 2nd question's scenario with combination's strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation $\frac3{10}\cdot\frac29$ in the first problem gives the probability of drawing a blueberry first and a chokeberry second; you need to double it to include the probability of drawing a chokeberry first and a blueberry second.

To solve the second problem by counting rather than by working directly with probabilities, you must look at the possible *sequences* of $4$ draws, not *sets* of $4$. There are $7^4$ possible sequences of draws, and $5^4$ of them include only green marbles, so the desired probability is

$$\frac{5^4}{7^4}=\left(\frac57\right)^4\;,$$

just as in the other calculation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am clear about 1st question's answer. But could I solve the 2nd problem with combination, ie: Selecting "GGGG" from $_{20}C_4$/$_{28}C_4$.

Comment: @neo-nant: You’re welcome! No, you can’t use combinations on the second question, because you’re drawing with replacement: you can draw the same marble more than once. This means that what you have to count are the possible *sequences* of colors drawn, like GGRG or RRRR, not possible *sets* of four marbles. $\binom{20}4$ is the number of *sets* of $4$ *different* things that you can draw from a set of $20$ things, but you’re not necessarily actually drawing a set of $4$ different marbles: you might get the same marble every time.